# Get directions in new window Google maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, drupal-7, window.open

I embedded a google map in my contact page with the google maps js api.

All I want to do now, is when people click my marker they go to maps.google.com to get directions and find more info.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        window.open('http://goo.gl/muSZ5','_blank');
    });
```

that is my, code, the url is a short url to maps.google.com with added parameters.

The script works, but the browers does not automatically go to the tab that it opens (because it is called by a javascript trigger)

does anyone know how I can solve this.

So, click the marker, new window(tab) opens, automatically go to that window(tab)

This is my full code:

```
  (function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.location_block = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            console.log('test');
            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.87760,4.41923),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.87760,4.41923),
                map: map,
                title: "Ilias",
                html: ""
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                window.open('http://goo.gl/maps/L3rK','_blank');
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

@EDIT @IMPORTANT
I found out the problem is only in google chrome, and only with my website ...

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine in my machine.Please check the following code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>​
```

**JS CODE:**

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 50, 50 ),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), myOptions ),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: myLatLng, map: map} );
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
       window.open('http://goo.gl/muSZ5','_blank');
    });
    marker.setMap( map );

}

initialize();
```

​
**CSS CODE:**

```
#map-canvas
{
height: 400px;
width: 500px;
}​
```

See [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kvJas/)

Comment: That is more ore less the code I have, but in my case the tab opens, but I stay in the original window. I am trying to put my code in js-fiddle

Comment: Ok I checked your code, manipulated it into my code. The problem is in JSFiddle it works correctly, In my drupal website it doesn't (still opens tab without going to it). So ther must be something changing this behaviour, do you have any idea what ?

Comment: Actually I dont have any idea about drupal. Can you just share your drupal code?

Comment: I will have it only later, but if you would have any idea towards why chrome would open a tab and not focus on it it would be a great help

Comment: Its working fine in chrome in my machine. Which version of chrome you are using?

Comment: It also works fine in chrome when I use jsfiddle, but not on my website. So something in my website is giving faulty behaviour in chrome. I am using version 20.x

Comment: Hope no problem with Chrome I think because I am using Chrome 20.0.1132.47 version. Hope something went wrong in website. Once check in developer tools whether it throwing any error.