# Working with Google maps on Windows store

Tags: google-maps, windows-8, windows-store-apps

[Google Maps on windows phone](http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/)

How can I add pushpins and get directions in here.
Do I require to use JavaScript

Comment: Are you looking for Windows Phone 8, or Windows Store/Windows 8? Your subject suggests the latter, but the text of the link says phone.

Comment: Actually it is Google maps on windows store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note in this method:

```
function addMarkers () {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.features.length; i++) {
        var quake = dataResults.features[i];
        var coors = quake.geometry.coordinates;
        var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(coors[1], coors[0]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLong,
            map: map
            //icon: getCircle(earthquake.properties.mag)
        });
    }
}
```

The important part in that is when we create a marker we give it a map object, which was initialized from the div 'mapdisplay' so we initialize that map object here

```
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdisplay'), {
        zoom: 3,
...
```

and in turn it is passed as the 'map' parameter in the call to:

```
new google.maps.Marker
```

This is using the returned earthquake data from the USGS and simply creating the new marker.
You can simply use a similar technique to add your own pins (ie markers), and yes - you need JavaScript : )
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

In order to get directions see "Displaying the DirectionsResult" at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
or an overview at
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

For a working sample (it's not win8 but it shouldn't matter as I'm assuming you are using a Windows 8 HTML/JS application)
[Get directions in new window Google maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231831/get-directions-in-new-window-google-maps-api-v3)

Now with that said - you can also use Bing Maps as well and it's quite documented for Windows 8 applications

[Bing Maps for Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846481.aspx)

[Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Maps-SDK-for-Metro-31b378eb)